# Getting posts related to a keyword

Tags: php, wordpress

I added a related posts box to my wordpress site.
The code I used was this http://pastebin.com/yqW9cJ9r it works for posts, but i want to use it also for another case where I don't want the tags of the post but rather a variable *$keyword*.
Is there a way to modify the code in such a way that it does that?
Best of regards.

Comment: Could you post your code here instead of pastebin?

Answer (score 0):

```
 <?php $orig_post = $post;
global $post;
$tags = wp_get_post_tags($post->ID);
if ($tags) {
$tag_ids = array();
foreach($tags as $individual_tag) $tag_ids[] = $individual_tag->term_id;
$args=array(
'tag__in' => $tag_ids,
'post__not_in' => array($post->ID),
'posts_per_page'=>5, // Number of related posts that will be shown.
'caller_get_posts'=>1
);
$my_query = new wp_query( $args );
if( $my_query->have_posts() ) {
echo '<div id="relatedposts"><h3>Related Posts</h3><ul>';
while( $my_query->have_posts() ) {
$my_query->the_post(); ?>
<li><div class="relatedthumb"><a href="<? the_permalink()?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?></a></div>
<div class="relatedcontent">
<h3><a href="<? the_permalink()?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
<?php the_time('M j, Y') ?>
</div>
</li>
<? }
echo '</ul></div>';
}
}
$post = $orig_post;
wp_reset_query(); ?>
```